# Prove that if the speed of a particle is constant, $\vec a$ is perpendicular to $\vec v$

Tags: proof-writing, physics, vectors

My train of reasoning (well, not even that, more like "translating") so far:

Let $C$ be some constant.
$\|\vec {v(t)}\|=C$, so $\frac {d\|\vec {v(t)}\|} {dt}=0$.

But, where to go from here? I don't know how to express $\frac {d\|\vec {v(t)}\|} {dt}=0$ in terms of $\vec a$, aside from just flatly saying "$\mathrm{comp}_va=0$", which I feel doesn't sound very smooth or explanatory.

Comment: [Tangential and centripetal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Tangential_and_centripetal_acceleration) might help.

Comment: Try working with the speed squared, recalling that it can be written as a dot product.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks, that was just the hint I needed! Will post up the solution shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from Semiclassical, I figured it out:

Let $C$ be some constant; we know
$||\vec {v(t)}||=C$ and $||\vec{v(t)}||^2=\vec v • \vec v$ so $\vec v • \vec v=C^2$ and $$\frac {d(\vec v • \vec v)} {dt}=2(\vec v • \frac {d \vec v} {dt})=0$$Therefore, $$\vec v • \vec a=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec {v(t)}\ = \|\vec {v(t)}\|(sin(\theta) + cos(\theta))$$
$$\therefore \vec a = \frac {d\vec {v(t)}} {dt}=\frac {d\|\vec {v(t)}\|} {dt}(sin(\theta) + cos(\theta)) + \|\vec {v(t)}\|\frac{d(sin(\theta) + cos(\theta))}{dt}$$
$$\therefore \vec a = 0 + \|\vec{v(t)}\|\frac{d\theta}{dt}(cos(\theta)-sin(\theta))$$
$$\therefore \vec a = \|\vec{v(t)}\|\frac{d\theta}{dt}(sin(\pi/2 + \theta)+cos(\pi/2 + \theta))$$

Thus, $\vec a$ is perpendicular to $\vec v.$

Answer (score -1):

a in direction of v = $\frac{d|v|}{dt}=0$
a in perpendicular direction of v = $\frac{|v^2|}{R}\ne0$ where R is radius of curvature